# Problemas com animação

Tags: ruby, script, rgss3

Existir um animação no jogo que do personagem atacando com a espada,
ah espada e uma imagem por tras do personagem, o código desenha assim.
mas meu verdadeiro problema e com Index, quando o jogador passa por um tipo de portal para ir para outro mapa, a `i` acaba sendo `Nill`

```
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # * Atualização do ataque
  #-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  def update_attack
      for i in 1..$game_temp.Player_HighIndex 
      if $game_system.PlayerAttacking(i)
      if @createdanim[i] == 0 
        create_anim(i)
        end
      if @createdanim[i].nil?
        create_anim(i)
      end
    end
    end

    if @anim.nil? || @count.nil? || @icon_index.nil? || @createdanim.nil?
      @anim = []
      @count = []
      @icon_index = []
      @createdanim = []

    end

    for i in 1..$game_temp.Player_HighIndex
    if @count[i] && @count[i] >= 0
      @anim[i].x = 1
      @anim[i].x = (StructManager.Player(i).X + 1 ) * 32 + Position[StructManager.Player(i).Dir][0] - 16
      @anim[i].y = (StructManager.Player(i).Y + 1 ) * 32 + Position[StructManager.Player(i).Dir][1] - 5
      case @count[i]
      when 12; set_angle(i, 0)
      when 9; set_angle(i, 1)
      when 6; set_angle(i, 2)
      when 3; set_angle(i, 3)
      when 0
        @anim[i].bitmap = nil
        @count[i] = nil
        @anim[i].visible = false
        @anim[i].dispose
        @anim[i] = nil
        $game_system.SetPlayerAttacking(i, false)
        @createdanim[i] = 0
      end
      @count[i] -= 1 if @count[i]
      end
    end
    @createdanim[i] == 0
 return;
  end
```

**Exp**

No caso

```
if @createdanim[i] == 0
```

acaba sendo `if @createdanim[Nill] == 0` se o jogador aperta o Z de mas na hora de passar pelo portal.

mas no caso teria que ser a `i` do jogador(`for i in 1..$game_temp.Player_HighIndex`).

Eu quero saber como faço para a animação não acontecer se o `i` for `Null` ou ate ele repeti a animação se for `Null`

Alguma dica pois eu ja tentem usar um `return if @createdanim[i] == Nill` ou `false` mas talvez n fiz da maneira correta.

**Possível solução.**

Acho que já entendie a fonte do problema, a `i` do jogador so atualiza uma vez, no caso se eu aperta o botão Z pela segunda vez o `i` = 0.

é ai que entra o

```
if @createdanim[i] == 0
    create_anim(i)
  end
```

quando o jogador muda de mapa o `def update_attack` atualiza e o `i` deixa de ser zero, então ta rolando um bug ja que isso essa duas ação e feita ao mesmo tempo.

então no caso tenho q fazer o `def update_attack` seja chamado toda vez que a pessoa aperta Z, para ta sempre atualizando a `i` do jogador.

Comment: Sinceramente nao deu pra entender nada dessa duvida. Qual linguagem? Clique em EDITAR  e explique melhor o problema.

Comment: RGSS3 eu acho que é chamada de Ruby.

Comment: Mas sua duvida está muito confusa ainda. Sugiro que clique em EDITAR e seja mais claro nela. Veja em **[ask]** como você pode melhorar ela.

Comment: Olha fis isso aqui para facilitar por que n consigo explicar melhor espero que ajude.      Eu quero saber como faço para a animação não acontecer se o i for Null ou ate ele repeti a animação se for Null